# Can I set the "-Server" parameter for use with Active Directory cmdlets per PS session?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm administering three domains (let's call them xx.company.local, xy.company.local, and xz.company.local) and I've got domain admin accounts for all three domains.

If I run powershell as my xx domain admin user I don't need to specify the -Server parameter for AD cmdlets, but I do when running PS as the other two. I assume this is because my PC is only joined to the xx domain.

Is there a command that I can run when opening up the xy and xz powershell sessions that will set that -Server parameter? (I'm looking into $PSHome and $PSDefaultParameterValues, but figured I would ask before wasting too much time.)

*Extra thought: I have three runas shortcuts for my ADUC gui (mmc.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\dsa.msc) and the one-time single-step for the xy and xz domains was to change the domain. I'm hoping that there's a similar step I can run for the powershell side of things.*

Comment: What do you mean by _opening up the xy and xz sessions_? Are connecting to a domain controller on those domains or invoking a command on a remote server joined to those domains? If this was the case, I don't believe specifying the server parameter would be needed.

Comment: opening powershell using runas with the domain admin user for either the xy or xz domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to modify my script since nobody posted an answer.

first, I created a global variable in my .psm1 file

```
$domain_controller = Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Service PrimaryDC
```

then, I created a new function

```
function Set-DomainController {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param( 
        [ValidateSet(“xx”, ”xy”, ”xz”)] 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string]
        $xxxyxz
    )
    process {
        if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('xxxyxz')) {
            $script:domain_controller = Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Service PrimaryDC -Domain "$xxxyxz.company.local"
        }
        else {

            Write-Output ""
            Write-Output "You are currently using " $script:domain_controller.Hostname
            Write-Output ""
            Write-Output "Select a domain:"
            Write-Output "[1] - xx.company.local"
            Write-Output "[2] - xy.company.local"
            Write-Output "[3] - xz.company.local"
            Write-Output ""
            $selection = Read-Host "Please make a selection"
            switch ($selection) {
                '1' {
                    $script:domain_controller = Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Service PrimaryDC -Domain xx.company.local
                } 
                '2' {
                    $script:domain_controller = Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Service PrimaryDC -Domain xy.company.local
                } 
                '3' {
                    $script:domain_controller = Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Service PrimaryDC -Domain xzcompany.local
                }    
            }
            Write-Output ""
            Write-Output "You are currently using " $script:domain_controller.Hostname
            Write-Output ""
        }
    }
}
Set-Alias -Name setdc -Value Set-DomainController
```

lastly I went through the rest of the functions in my module and added `-Server $script:domain_controller` to every Get-AD* call throughout

took a few hours, but now it's done
... still looking for something better ...